# How to set date with time in sxw using python for openerp report?

Tags: date, time

I am generation report in openerp. that ways is, I created sxw and convet into rml then rml into pdf. It is working fine now. What my doubts is, when try to get date and time field value, it's getting only date. Time is not coming in pdf report.

Field name in python: 'sample_receipt_date':datetime(....)

in sxw:   [[formatLang(o.sample_receipt_date,date=True)]]

After convert pdf: dd/mm/yy

but i want this format dd/mm/yy/min/sec in pdf.

what is python coding in sxw document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[ time.ctime() ]]` should work in RML, otherwise, take a look at https://doc.openerp.com/6.1/vi/developer/05_reports/ or the full [RML for Idiots](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml-for-idiots.pdf) manual

Comment: I want to get date and time value from this field 'sample_receipt_date':fields.datetime('Sample Recept Date'). Could you tell me exactly?

Comment: This function giving current time (Fri May 30 04:06:18 2014
) in this format. I want to get date and time value from my field 'sample_receipt_date':fields.datetime('Sample Recept Date'). And I want this format (05/03/2014 07:11)

Comment: Try the strftime() method. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm

Comment: [[formatLang(o.sample_receipt_date_report)),date=True]] this line in docments(sxw). and I am converting this file rml. that time it takes date. time is not coming.
[[time.strftime(formatLang(o.sample_receipt_date_report)),date=True]] this is not working

Comment: Take a look at page 31 of the RML for Idiot manual I sent you. There is no reasons for it not to work. Create a script and a variable with the content of your object, and then print the value of that variable.

Comment: As you said in last comment, I created separate char field and set what i get from date field. so It is converting date into string automatically. I am getting this value to sxw document. It will print date and time as normal string. Now is working fine. Thanks lot

Comment: Could you please answer me? I have tried last 3 months. i don't get answer still now.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139244/how-to-display-name-on-qr-code-in-openerp

Comment: Sorry, but I'm no help on that, since I've never done anything like that before :) Good luck!

Comment: could you please correct this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118056/how-to-set-download-path-my-own-file

Comment: Hi Filipe Castanheira, can you please tell what problem with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607823/keyerror-when-import-data-in-openerp

Comment: I guess I'am late since you've already found the answer. Good job! :)

Comment: Hi Filipe Castanheira, can you please tell what problem with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733796/how-to-remove-attachment-for-specific-model-in-openrp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
replace (date=True) By (date_time=True)
```