# keyError, When import data in openerp

Tags: string, import, odoo, openerp-7, keyerror

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140112_001021-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140112_001021-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140112_001021-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base_import/models.py", line 219, in parse_preview
    fields = self.get_fields(cr, uid, record.res_model, context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140112_001021-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base_import/models.py", line 116, in get_fields
    cr, uid, field['relation'], context=context, depth=depth-1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140112_001021-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base_import/models.py", line 116, in get_fields
    cr, uid, field['relation'], context=context, depth=depth-1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140112_001021-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base_import/models.py", line 103, in get_fields
    'string': field['string'],
KeyError: 'string'
```

I am getting this error, When i import in customer form. This form inherited from res_partner.
this is csv file.

```
id,"name"
__export__.res_partner_10,"1"
__export__.res_partner_11,"2"
__export__.res_partner_579,"abrajeethan"
__export__.res_partner_640,"Abu"
__export__.res_partner_584,"ahmekldsgjfmkp"
__export__.res_partner_469,"Anand"
__export__.res_partner_672,"aniasdftha"
__export__.res_partner_49,"Ayantasdfika"
__export__.res_partner_481,"Aasdfyantikr"
```

csv format is working fine, when i import other form. But not working in customer.

xml code:

```
<record id="extended_view_partner_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Customers</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Contacts">
                <field name="client_id"/>
                <field name="clientadded_date"/>
                <field name="branch"/>
                <field name="phone"/>
                <field name="email"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
</record>
```

Can you please tell how to clear this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer. In addons/base_import folder at models.py file. in 103 line.

I have changed as

```
'string':fields.get('string'),
```

instead of

```
'string':fields['string']
```